# Lync - PowerShell - User status

Tags: powershell, administration, lync, querying

G'day everyone,
I was checking out Lync PowerShell Blog and couldn't find much about querying Lync server for users by status (Available, Busy etc). There's [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378560.aspx) but it is for the SDK, can anyone give an example of retrieving users by their online status?
Also, is there a way to distinguish the kind of Lync they're running, because it's different when users are logged in on mobiles and it displays "Mobile" in status I believe.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this link.  Its from TechNet.  I believe the code sample in the post demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish.

[List the Users and Client Endpoint Versions Connected to a Registrar Pool: Remote Connection](http://blogs.technet.com/b/csps/archive/2011/03/10/list_2d00_users_2d00_and_2d00_endpoints_2d00_remote.aspx)

Comment: Credit where credit is due, fantastic, thanks for that GlennFerrieLive!

Comment: no sweat. glad I could help.  I have struggled with this issue myself.

Comment: Perhaps you would know how to distinguish mobile from pc users?

Comment: Hmm. that is a good one.  Can you post that as a second question?  (no bounty)